# How to filter geom_text based on one category in a factor variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I plot the following graph below. I use geom_text to show the highest unemployment rate for the specific country that is highlighted in blue. However, i get the highest unemployment among the six countries plotted.
I tried to filter geom_text keeping only France by doing the following: `unemp == max(df$unemp) & cntry=="France"` instead of using only `unemp == max(df$unemp)`. But this did not work. Could someone help with it please?

Here is the plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(year, unemp), color=cntry)+
  geom_line(aes(group=cntry, color=cntry), size=1.5)+
  geom_line(data = df[df$cntry == 'France',], aes(group=cntry, color=cntry), size=1.5)+
  geom_text(data = filter(df, unemp == max(df$unemp)), aes(year, unemp, label = round(unemp, 3)), hjust = 2.25, size=7) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('dark blue','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999'))
```

[image]

Here is the data:

```
     df= structure(list(cntry = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("France", 
"Germany", "Italy", "Poland", "Spain", "United Kingdom"), class = "factor"), 
    year = c(2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
    2010, 2011, 2012, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 
    2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
    2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 
    2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 
    2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2002, 2003, 2004, 
    2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012), unemp = c(8, 
    9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 7, 9, 9, 9, 10, 9, 10, 10, 11, 10, 9, 7, 8, 
    7, 6, 5, 9, 8, 8, 8, 7, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 11, 20, 20, 19, 18, 
    14, 10, 7, 8, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 9, 8, 8, 11, 18, 20, 
    21, 25, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8)), row.names = c(NA, 
-66L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making use of `dplyr::slice_max` this could be achieved like so:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

d_fra <- filter(df, cntry == 'France')

ggplot(df, aes(year, unemp), color=cntry)+
  geom_line(aes(group=cntry, color=cntry), size=1.5)+
  geom_line(data = d_fra, aes(group=cntry, color=cntry), size=1.5)+
  geom_text(data = slice_max(d_fra, unemp, n = 1), aes(year, unemp, label = round(unemp, 3)), hjust = 2.25, size=7) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('dark blue','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999'))
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry to bother again, but i was wondering, if i am interested to plot the values of a certain year (e.g., 2002) instead of the highest or lowest value. How, would the code change then?

Comment: Hi Jad. You are welcome. If you want to label a specific year you could do `geom_text(data = filter(d_fra, year == 2002), ...`.